# Does std::copy_n work with overlapping ranges?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, stl-algorithm

I was looking in the C++ standard at N3485 25.3.1 [alg.copy], which defines 4 algorithms:

- `copy`
- `copy_backward`
- `copy_if`
- `copy_n`

In the description for `copy`, there is this note 25.3.1 [alg.copy]/3:

> Requires: result shall not be in the range [first,last)

That is, `copy` does not always work correctly when the ranges overlap (similar to `memcpy`).

`copy_backward` and `copy_if` have similar language prohibiting overlapping ranges (25.3.1 [alg.copy]/14 and 25.3.1 [alg.copy]/8, respectively).

However, there is no such prohibition for `copy_n`, and there is no `copy_n_backward`. Does this mean that `copy_n` does the right thing when the ranges overlap?

(MSVC++'s implementation of `copy_n` appears to delegate to `std::memmove`, so I know it is safe here on MSVC++ 2013. But I don't want to rely on this if the standard implies otherwise)

Comment: "MSVC++'s implementation of `copy_n` appears to delegate to `std::memmove`" Note that we only do this where such a transformation is correct; that is, where the iterators are pointers to trivially copyable objects.

Comment: @James: Of course. :) In this case it happens that this is a safe transformation.

Comment: @James: Ah, I see your point. If the inputs were e.g. `std::list` iterators, it would be unsafe on MSVC++'s implementation. Sounds like an answer to me...

Comment: Wow that's an odd edge case, I want to say it's probably a mistake (they intended it to be UB) but it seems almost deliberately left out...

Comment: The original [SGI implementation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/copy_n.html) did have such a requirement for `copy_n`. I have no idea why this is not in the Standard. You could submit an issue. BTW, `copy` only prohibits overlap for which the output *starts* in the input range, but works fine when the output range *ends* ind the input range (i.e. copying to the left).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is safe*. Why? Because the standard doesn't say it *isn't* safe. They copy functions from 25.3.1 have *Requires:* for things they require (this is where the overlapping prohibition is stated in the other copy forms).

However, `copy_n` does *not* say it requires that the ranges do not overlap, which means it's okay, as it's not explicitly prohibited. If it required it, it would state it.

***Edit:** When I meant "safe" I meant it's not undefined behavior or an illformed program to do so. However, the results aren't guaranteed to be what you probably intended if the memory ranges overlap. The only thing we are guaranteed is:

1. For each non-negative integer `i < n`, `*(result + i) = *(first + i)` is performed
2. Calling the function with overlapping ranges is not prohibited and does not result in undefined behavior.

We can thus deduce that if the ranges overlap, then the results stored in the destination are no longer guaranteed to be an exact (in-order) copy of the source. We are guaranteed that every value in the destination will have come from the source, though exactly which values those are depends on the overlap and the exact order in which elements are copied.

So if by "safe" you mean that the destination always has a perfect copy of the source (like `memmove`), then no, it's not "safe". But it is safe in the sense that it won't cause undefined/invalid behavior in and of itself.

To recap, we are guaranteed that `*(result + i) = *(first + i)` will be done for every element in the entire range. We are guaranteed that if the ranges overlap, the program is still not undefined. We are not guaranteed the order in which the elements are copied. We are not guaranteed that if the ranges overlap, what the exact values stored in the result will be (but we do know that they all came from the source).

Comment: How does `copy_n` do the safety check when the iterators don't support random access? (It requires only an input iterator and an output iterator....)

Comment: @Billy cplusplus.com says `If the ranges overlap, some of the elements in the range pointed by result may have undefined but valid values.` But I don't know how reliable that is.

Comment: @remyabel: cplusplus.com == unreliable as hell. :)

Comment: @BillyONeal: Updated. Sorry, I initially meant "safe" differently than you were probably using it.

Comment: So passing overlapping ranges is permitted, but actually doing so has unpredictable results and is therefore useless in every conceivable case? What a strange spec. Why not treat this the same as the other `copy` functions? What could they possibly have been thinking? (I agree that is what the spec appears to say, so +1. But how bizarre.)

Comment: @Nemo: I agree it's bizarre. I wish they either prohibited it, or at least explicitly said "you can do this, but you might get junk back."

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Cornstalks' answer, and +1 to it. But, theory must be backed by practice.

A quick peek at the implementations of GCC (libstdc++-v3) and Clang (libc++) shows that their `copy_n` is the same as (or delegates to) `copy`, with no support for overlapping when moving objects to higher addresses.

So, MSVC wins this round, at least in the POD case which delegates to `memmove`.